# ASP.Net Confirm box issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my asp.net application I have used JavaScript confirm box for user confirmation.
Here is the code:

**EDIT :**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed with the delete?');"/>
```

This is working grate `Button1_Click` is only called when user clicks `OK`. But I have more complex logic which changes on users replay. Here is the code for it:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        // I want to catch replay of this confirm box     
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Termination Failed", "confirm('This Contract Have a Pre-Renewed,Please Delete that Contract First')",true);

    //If User Clicks ok
     doWork();

    //else
    doWork2();            
    }
```

But I am unable to get user response. How can I catch user response? Can any one help?

Comment: Right. You managed to do an event handler Button1_Click and now you want to do Button2_Click... right? Seems quite simple... Right? Right.

Comment: yes but my button2_click is JS confirms OK

Comment: @Ashutosh can you please tell me how you are using your button ?

Comment: @Ashutosh I have updated my answer please try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using javascript confirm method you only decide, whether you want to continue or not - so it is ok that your `Button1_Click` method is called only when user clicks *ok*.

What you trying to do is quite different. I would suggest to get rid of ASP.NET Button control and use "common" HTML link like:

```
<a href="#" id="decideLink">Click me</a>
```

And then in javascript

```
document.getElementById('decideLink').onclick = function()
{
    if(proceed) {
        // do something here
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

To call code-behind method from javascript, check this [article about calling web methods from javascript](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution use javascript and call `OnClientClick`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirm() {
           if (confirm('This Contract Have a Pre-Renewed,Please Delete that Contract First')) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
      </script>     
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return  
 confirm()"/>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I thought he was talking about page_load event and not a button click. Removed -1